# How to delete django migrations after squashing them?

Tags: django, migration, django-migrations, squash

Django documentation says we could delete migrations after squashing them:

> You should commit this migration but leave the old ones in place; the
>   new migration will be used for new installs. Once you are sure all
>   instances of the code base have applied the migrations you squashed,
>   you can delete them.

Here, does deleting means deleting only the migration files, or the entries in the django_migrations table as well?

Here is some background: I have only the development machine, so just one code base. After squashing some of the migrations that I had already applied, I deleted the files and the database entries. Tested if this is OK by making migrations, it did not find anything. So, everything looked good. Next day, I had to change something, and made migration. When I tried to migrate, it tried to apply the squashed migration too (which was applied part by part before being squashed). So, I had to go back and recreate the entries in the django_migrations table. So, it seems like I had to keep the database entries. I am trying to make sure before I mess up anything again, and understand why it looked fine first, and then tried to apply the squashed migration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Squashed migrations are never marked as applied, which will be fixed in 1.8.3 (see [#24628](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24628)).

The steps to remove the old migrations are:

1. Make sure all replaced migrations are applied (or none of them).
2. Remove the old migration files, remove the `replaces` attribute from the squashed migrations.
3. (Workaround) Run `./manage.py migrate <app_label> <squashed_migration> --fake`.

The last step won't be necessary when 1.8.3 arrives.

Answer (score 2):

Converting squashed migrations has gotten easier since the question was posted. I posted a [small sample project](https://github.com/donkirkby/djsquash/tree/convert_squash) that shows how to squash migrations with circular dependencies, and it also shows how to convert the squashed migration into a regular migration after all the installations have migrated past the squash point.

As the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) says:

> You must then transition the squashed migration to a normal migration by:
>
> - Deleting all the migration files it replaces.
> - Updating all migrations that depend on the deleted migrations to depend on the squashed migration instead.
> - Removing the replaces attribute in the Migration class of the squashed migration (this is how Django tells that it is a squashed migration).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert by any means, but I just squashed my migrations, and ended up doing the following:

Ran this query to removed the old migrations (squashed)

```
DELETE FROM south_migrationhistory;
```

Run this management command to remove the ghosted migrations

```
./manage.py migrate --fake --delete-ghost-migrations
```

Django 1.7 also has [squashmigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-squashmigrations)

Comment: I should have mentioned I used Django 1.8, so this is not a south migration. Thanks for the answer though.